# SSAS 2005 dsv table from view wrong primary key

Tags: ssas

I created a table in DSV from a view:

```
        CREATE VIEW xxx
        AS
            select  ID, code,  description from dbo.xxx
            where r_types = 'd'
```

The underlying table (xxx) has ID as primary key. But when I added this view in DSV SSAS automatically identify code as the primary key. Why? And How can I change this?

Comment: Where are you seeing that SSAS automatically identified it as the primary key? Did you try to change it?

Comment: @mmarie I saw it when I added the view in data source view. SSAS put a primary key icon beside the code column. I actually used the ' replacing  table with named query' to use the query instead of the view. Then I can manually assign id as primary key. Just curious is there a better way to do this and why SSAS think code is primary key when the view is used.